# Spring XD: Is it possible to have multiple jobs in a single module

Tags: java, spring-batch, spring-xd

I'm using Spring XD to execute a batch task, which itself is divided into two separate jobs living in the same (job:)module. 
Now I'm quite new to Spring XD/Batch so I only have a rather basic understanding of the framework. I'd like to know if there's a way to address each of those jobs separately? I know I can deploy a job giving it the modules name, however I haven't found a way to specify which job I want to deploy.

Should there be only one job per module? And if not, how can I talk to/deploy each of those jobs separately?

Please let me know if the description of the problem is unclear.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Spring XD requires one "main" job to be executed within the module.  That being said, Spring XD does support Spring Batch's concept of nested jobs where one job is used to orchestrate the launching of multiple jobs which sounds like it would fit your bill.  The "main" job is required to have the id "job".  After that, that job can call any number of other jobs packaged in the same module via job steps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! The reason why I went for two jobs is, that both of them are triggered by different events (HTTP vs rabbitmq), although they actually are a logical unit (doWork() -> cleanUp()). So, another module it is then.